# Strange behavior of Chrome browser with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser

I heve some code line. Why Mozilla Firefox take **first saveImage()** properly and Chrome take **second** saveImage. Even if console.log($('#param-form').size()) = 0   ???
I use Jquery 1.7.2. with length instead size() it's the same result.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   if ($('#catalog-image-form').size()) {
       function saveImage() {
           some logic 1
       } 
   }

   if ($('#param-form').size()) {
      function saveImage() {
         some logic 2 
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: "The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the .length property instead."
http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: Show u HTML code. -> http://jsfiddle.net/ plz

Comment: Can you please share the logic that you have written along with the html ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a problem with [function hoisting](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=javascript%20function%20hoisting)?

Answer (score 0):

Beside what +Jaroslaw said about the .size() method being deprecated as jQuery 1.8, have you tried this?

```
if ($('#param-form').size() > 0)
```

You test 2 different selectors, are you sure Chrome does not execute both saveImage() ?

Comment: Chrome still take second saveImage() and Mozilla take first

Answer (score 0):

At script loading, Chrome should search all global **function** declaration to optimize/pre-compile the code inside, in order of declaration.

If you declare the function at the runtime, using **= function**, the declaration is done only if the line is executed.

So, in your case, define the function at runtime with **saveImage = function () {…}**.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   if ($('#catalog-image-form').size()) {
       saveImage = function () {
           $("#input1").val("some logic 1");
       }
       function globalfunction () {
           $("#input1").val("some logic 1");
       }
   }

   if ($('#param-form').size()) {
      saveImage = function () {
         $("#input1").val("some logic 2");
      }
      function globalfunction () {
         $("#input2").val("some logic 2");
      }
   }

   if (false) {
      saveImage = function () {
         $("#input1").val("some logic 3");
      }
       function globalfunction () {
           $("#input2").val("some logic 3");
       }
   }
  
  saveImage();
  globalfunction();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="catalog-image-form">
  <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1"/>
  <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2"/>
</form>
```